# What will happen if the password is changed for the user we used to create a Key Vault using Visual Studio Connected Services

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I am reading this article @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service on how to secure our data inside our application using Key Vault connected service.. but inside the article it mentioned that following:-

```
Sign in with the same account that you use for your Azure subscription
```

so my question is, what will happen to the Key Vault connected service if the username is deleted/disabled or its password is changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use another user (who has access to the Azure key vault) to sign into Visual Studio and then you can access your secrets.

For how to assign the access (RBAC role) to another user, please refer to [Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

You can find the key vault in Azure portal to do the operation (for example, assign the **Owner** role of the key vault to the user).

If the another user is the owner of the Azure subscription, you do not need to make additional RBAC role assignments. He already has permission to access this key vault.